# How to find height of mozilla firefox full web page in mfc c++

Tags: c++, mfc

i have done lot of work on it, but couldn't find the height of mozilla firefox full web page.

i use this code in all the way according to information given on the different sites, but couldn't find the  **ISimpleDOMNode** object.

```
IServiceProvider *pServProv = NULL;
pAccessible->QueryInterface(IID_IServiceProvider, (void**)&pServProv);
ISimpleDOMNode *pSimpleDOMNode;
if (pServProv) {
const GUID refguid = {0x0c539790, 0x12e4, 0x11cf, 0xb6, 0x61,
                    0x00, 0xaa, 0x00, 0x4c, 0xd6, 0xd8};
HRESULT result = pServProv->QueryService(refguid, IID_ISimpleDOMNode,
                                       (void**)&pSimpleDOMNode);
if (SUCCEEDED(hresult) && pSimpleDOMNode != NULL) {
 /* This is a Mozilla node! Use special ISimpleDOMNode methods described in
    ISimpleDOMNode.idl. */
 }
}
```

plz, help me on this.

thanks.

Comment: [ISimpleDOMNode.idl](http://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/accessible/interfaces/msaa/ISimpleDOMNode.idl). No idea why you hope to get information about the host window through a DOM node.

Comment: I just want to know about height of web page so that i can scroll it for capturing the whole page, but not getting any idea how to achieve this.I thought DOMDocument by the DOM node can give this but not giving.

Answer (score 0):

Well, have you looked at the ISimpleDOMNode.idl file as it says in the comment?

Comment: hello roel, this is asking for MPL 1.1/GPL 2.0 licence,but there are no steps, how to use that. some copying statement are given for the GPL. i used that, but no benefits.